# When a country is banned from using SWIFT, what alternative ways do banks within that country still have to transfer or receive money from abroad?

Tags: international-trade, banking, money

If Russia invades Ukraine one of the sanctions that the west might impose is banning the banks in Russia from the [SWIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_for_Worldwide_Interbank_Financial_Telecommunication) network. I've watched [a short video from a financial news channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1R3hcYBLN4&ab_channel=RTLZ) that explains the consequences of such a ban for Russia.

In the video the reporter says that such a ban will hamper russian banks from transfering money abroad or receiving money from abroad. However such a ban would not completely prevent these banks from transfering or receiving money from abroad. There are still alternative ways that these banks could employ but these ways would be a lot slower then SWIFT.

My question is: **What are those alternative ways exactly? How would these alternative transfer methods work and what makes them slower?**

Thank you